# How to create formula with choices list?

Tags: formula, opportunity, picklist

I want to create a priorization system within my opportunities. It should be a field showing the output of `amount * probability * boost-factor`. Boost factor is supposed to be a gut feeling about the opportunity. It only has three values, `0.75` for a slightly negative impression ,`1` for a normal impression and `1.25` for a good feeling.

I tried to set up a custom field for `boost`, with a picklist with three values. The user should choose the boost factor according to her impression of the opportunity. I then created a new formula field `Priority`, which should compute the above mentioned output. However, picklists are not supported, when holding anything else but text ([Link](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=tips_on_building_formulas.htm&siteLang=en_US#picklists_and_msps)).

How can I set up my priorities, if not with a picklist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go ahead and have those values as text in the picklist, then when it comes to your formula convert them using the function VALUE(TEXT(myPicklistField__c)).
The text function converts the picklist into text, the value converts a text string that represents a number to a number.
Does that help?

Your formula would look something like

```
amount__c * probability__c * VALUE(TEXT(boost-factor__c))
```

As a side note, if you wanted the user to choose from text values in the picklist, you could do a conversion to numeric factor in the formula itself.

Suppose you have the three picklist values 'Negative', 'Normal', 'Good' then you could rewrite your formula field as

```
amount__c * probability__c * CASE(Boost_Factor__c, 'Negative', 0.75, 'Normal', 1, 'Good', 1.25, 1)   //final argument is the default if no match
```